# Inline styling inside javascript of web component

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to add a custom scrollbar to a web component.

I am not very familiar with web components but i understand that it is difficult to apply pseudo-elements to parts. From my reading, one way to apply styling in the shadow dom that might work is to include the style inline in the javascript of the component? However my js skills aren't good enough to know where to place it in the js! Can anyone advise, where should the style go in the below to apply styles to modal class within the x-modal component?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

```js
// js/common/overlay/modal.js
import { animate as animate5, timeline as timeline2 } from "vendor";
var Modal = class extends DialogElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.setAttribute("aria-modal", "true");
  }
  get shadowDomTemplate() {
    return this.getAttribute("template") || "modal-default-template";    
  }
  get shouldLock() {
    return true;
  }
  get shouldAppendToBody() {
    return true;
  }
  createEnterAnimationControls() {
    if (matchesMediaQuery("sm")) {
      return animate5(this, { opacity: [0, 1] }, { duration: 0.2 });
    } else {
      return timeline2([
        [this.getShadowPartByName("overlay"), { opacity: [0, 1] }, { duration: 0.3, easing: [0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1] }],
        [this.getShadowPartByName("content"), { transform: ["translateY(100%)", "translateY(0)"] }, { duration: 0.3, easing: [0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1], at: "<" }]
      ]);
    }
  }
  createLeaveAnimationControls() {
    if (matchesMediaQuery("sm")) {
      return animate5(this, { opacity: [1, 0] }, { duration: 0.2 });
    } else {
      return timeline2([
        [this.getShadowPartByName("overlay"), { opacity: [1, 0] }, { duration: 0.3, easing: [0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1] }],
        [this.getShadowPartByName("content"), { transform: ["translateY(0)", "translateY(100%)"] }, { duration: 0.3, easing: [0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1], at: "<" }]
      ]);
    }
  }
};

if (!window.customElements.get("x-modal")) {
  window.customElements.define("x-modal", Modal);
}
```

```css
.modal::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
} /* SUB background of the scrollbar except button or resizer */
.modal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #fff;
} /* SUB scrollbar itself */
.modal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #babac0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
} /* SUB set button(top and bottom of the scrollbar) */
.modal::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding inside your `connectedCallback()` method: `const modalElement = this.getShadowPartByName("content").querySelector(".modal");
    modalElement.style.scrollbarColor = "#provide_some_hex_color";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the **constructor** in the modal class in your code.

Please modify your code.

```
var Modal = class extends DialogElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // todo: here add shadow dom
    }
    ...
```

And then you need to use **Shadow DOM**.

> It hides the markup structure, styles, and behavior from the rest of the code on the page.

A reference code.

```
<style>
  .content {
    background: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
<body>
<x-modal/>
</body>
<script>
  class Modal extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()

      let style = document.createElement("style");
      style.textContent = `
          .modal::-webkit-scrollbar {
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 16px;
            overflow: auto;
          }

          /* SUB background of the scrollbar except button or resizer */
          .modal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: #fff;
          }

          /* SUB scrollbar itself */
          .modal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #babac0;
            border-radius: 16px;
            border: 4px solid #fff;
          }

          /* SUB set button(top and bottom of the scrollbar) */
          .modal::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
            display: none;
          }

          .modal {
            overflow: scroll;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid;
          }

          .content {
            height: 700px;
            background: red;
          }`

      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const content = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add("modal")
      content.classList.add("content")
      content.textContent = "this is a modal"
      div.appendChild(content)
      this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(div);
    }
  }

  if (!window.customElements.get("x-modal")) {
    window.customElements.define("x-modal", Modal);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: If no ``constructor`` is defined, the ``constructor`` from its **parent Class** is invoked. Its OOP. In OPs original code that will be in the (not listed) ``DialogElement`` (or its parent, or its parent.. or .. you get the drift)

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman
You're right, we don't know what's in his "DialogElement".

Answer (score 0):

We got here because Chromium doesn't support `::part(name)::webkit-scrollbar` yet.

So you want to **inject** that `webkit` stuff straight into a shadowDOM

Changing a `mode:"open"` shadowDOM is doable **after it was created in the DOM**, but a PITA

Easier is to stick to the OOP stuff and **extend** your own `my-x-modal` from the original `x-modal`
Then **append** an extra `<style>` tag to the shadowDOM

```html
<my-x-modal color="green">FOO</my-x-modal>
<my-x-modal color="blue">FOO</my-x-modal>
<script>
  const element = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
  customElements.define("x-modal", class extends HTMLElement { // ORIGINAL <X-MODAL>
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .append(
          element("STYLE",{
           innerHTML : 
            `:host{display:inline-block;overflow:scroll}` +
            `:host::-webkit-scrollbar { background: red }` // ORIGINAL COLOR
          }),
          element("SLOT")
        );
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML += "BAR";
    }
  });
  customElements.whenDefined("x-modal").then(() => {
    // CREATE YOUR OWN <MY-X-MODAL>
    customElements.define("my-x-modal", class extends customElements.get("x-modal") {
      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback && super.connectedCallback();
        this.shadowRoot.append(
          element("STYLE", {
            // OVERLOAD COLOR
            innerHTML: `:host::-webkit-scrollbar { background: ${this.getAttribute("color")} }`
          }),
          element("SPAN", {
            innerHTML: `BAZ`
          })
        );
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

FYI The original Wordle was a Web Component. With the above method it was "enhanced" to do:
https://mordle.github.io/?sentence=danny,hacks,super,wordle,wordle,lingo,words

Long blog post:
https://dev.to/dannyengelman/more-wordle-mordle-extending-josh-his-web-components-4li

Comment: Thanks Danny '365CSI' Engelman.  I've been playing around with this. Unfortunately i don't have the option to add my-x-modal web component to the markup, so i'm looking for a way to style x-modal itself. No need to dynamically get attributes etc as only one style will be needed. Is there no way to apply the webkit styling directly within the js code? Similar to as suggested by @nano71.com above? Thanks.